# Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1

Tags: flutter, dart

Android Studio version 4.2.1
Dart SDK 2.13.3
Flutter SDK 2.2.2
flutter doctor No issues found! (Проблем не обнаружено!)
Я подключаю телефон и нажимаю Run main.dart (Shift + F10). Появляется такая ошибка почти всегда, очень редко все получается нормально, скриншот прикрепил. До обновления flutter и Android Studio таких проблем не было. В эмуляторах работает нормально, в телефоне нет. Если у кого-то была такая проблема, подскажите, что нужно сделать, возможно включить или отключить какую-то опцию в настройках Android Studio.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: странно, что в эмуляторах все было норм. Я так понял сервер запускается на телефоне? И если нет, в случае с эмуляторами, настраивали какой-нибудь port forwarding?